# Selecting multiple rows from another table for one primary key

Tags: javascript, mysql, sql, json

The project I am working on is a cocktail recipe database that is stored in this fashion:

Cocktail Table:

- id (Primary Key, INT)
- name (TEXT)

Ingredient Table:

- id (Same as the cocktail, can have more than 1 ingredient with) (INT)
- ingredient name (TEXT)

I was hoping to create a select statement that would give me the following output for each cocktail:

- id
- name
- ingredient names in an array

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated

So far I understand how to get the rows from one table:
`SELECT * FROM cocktail_table`
and getting the matching ingredients for each recipe:
`SELECT * FROM cocktail_ingredients WHERE id = ?`
Then putting in the ID of the cocktail where the ? is.

Comment: A [mcve] is a great start when asking for SQL assistance. Note that homework related questions are expected to prove some extra effort.

Comment: Added the SQL I have right now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use "group_concat" function like below:

```
select c.id,c.name,GROUP_CONCAT(i.ingredient SEPARATOR ', ')
from cocktail c
inner join Ingredient i on c.id=i.id
group by c.id,c.name
```

See this fiddle for demonstration: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/35f6bc6/5